# When does one's account become unbanned?

Tags: discussion

My main account was banned from asking questions due to asking too many uninteresting questions. Do I have to make new accounts, whenever my older accounts are banned? I find this kinda buries the idea behind banning people. I also dislike having to switch between accounts. Fortunately my main account is well received on any other site. Thus I hope for this site to have a better way to deal with this.

Comment: *I hope for this site to have a better way to deal with this.*  Good questions are voted up; bad questions are voted down.  The site dealt with it just fine.

Comment: you have an option to delete your account and restart at slower rate (one question a week), [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773)

Comment: @gnat, thank you! This was very enlightening! I don't have a problem starting a slower rate.

Comment: It sounds like the site is dealing with it pretty well; you kept asking bad questions and now you can't. You should be changing, not SO.

Comment: First thing you should do is to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to make sure you are not asking off-topic questions and/or bad questions. Otherwise, you will just end up in same place you are now.

Answer (score 9):

*"Do I have to make new accounts and ask questions, whenever my older accounts are banned?"*

### No.

You try to improve the quality of the questions on your existing account, to get that one unbanned.
The "Question ban" message has a link that should help you with that.

In almost all cases it is not a good idea to create a new account when you're banned, and Stack Overflow is no exception.
There is no such thing as "Main" and "alternative" accounts on SO. There's just your original account, and ban evasion accounts.

To clarify:

SO question banned you. That happened for a reason.
Don't try to circumvent the ban by creating a new account. Improve your *existing* questions instead, and learn from past mistakes.

Comment: One cannot improve his/her questions, when one does get banned from asking further questions.... 
I find the questions about in "what world" rather redundant. Obviously: If one needs help, cannot help himself/herself, the questions is proper and finds asking others for help doesn't cause any problem, then one should do it. (This disregards the benefit of others to read about the problem, the answers and maybe learn something from it.)

Comment: You don't post new questions. You improve the quality of your _existing_ questions. One _shouldn't_ create ban evasion accounts. There really isn't any excuse on any site to make a new account after the site restricts your access. Go through the proper channels instead. (In this case, that means improving your existing questions).

Comment: @blauerschluessel A question isn't proper because you consider it proper (because *you* need help).  It's proper if it's a high-quality question that benefits *others* down the road.

Comment: Editing older, considered "not good" questions seems fine as it would raise the overall value of the site (which is probably the idea behind it.) - When I have the time, I will try that in the future.

Comment: @PetahChristian, I didn't write that. I made a list of properties a question should have in order to be stated. Being insensitive, selfish is rather stupid, but that should be common sense.

Comment: @PetahChristian, btw. I find the idea of high quality questions etc. rather ridiculous as high quality is by no means well defined. I consider a question to be proper, if it suffices the common sense qualities, (quality - in the sense of level of knowledge or skill has nothing to do with it)

Comment: @blauerschluessel: "Common sense" includes a clear problem statement, and _some kind_ of effort by the OP. Basically, it's common sense to write a good question if you want a good answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus, what do you want to hint? Do you say I put no effort into my others questions so far? That my other questions are not clear cut? By no means I decline, my questions could not be better. However nonetheless I  find this statement of yours perplexing.

Comment: @blauerschluessel: The system question banned you for a reason. That reason is usually that questions are poorly received due to them being of low quality, for some reason.